# Excel Custom Number Format on chart Axis

Tags: excel, formatting, number-formatting

I'm trying to set a Custom format for the Y-Axis of an Excel Chart and I'm not getting the result I need.  I've referenced the [Peltier](http://peltiertech.com/Excel/NumberFormats.html) webpage as a good source of information on creating custom Excel formats.  I've come up with the following.

`[>=1000000]0,,"M";[>=1000]0,"K";0`

It works well until I need the rage to show values like 1 million, 1.2 million, 1.4 million, ect...  I've tried

`[>=1000000]0.#,,"M";[>=1000]0,"K";0`

It does display 1.2M and 1.4M as needed but it has a period on the 1 million line "1. M".   How do I modify my format to only show the period when the number to right of the decimal point is not zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like the best approach to allow the Axis to scale normally is to show a Zero on the right hand side of the decimal point, therefore always showing decimal point.

So, using 
`[>=1000000]0.0,,"M";[>=1000]0,"K";0`

produces 
`800K, 1.0M, 1.2M, 1.4M, 1.6M, 1.8M, 2M, 2.2M`

Answer (score 0):

Without sample data together with expected results this may require some tweaking but you can add a specific circumstance to remove the decimal point. One of these might be appropriate.

```
[>1000000]0.0,,\M;[=1000000]0,,\M;0.0,K
[>1000999]0.0,,\M;[>999000]0,,\M;0.0,K
```

Comment: Okay, I see where you're going, but I guess i didn't make my bigger issue clear.  If I have the following major values for a chart `800000,1000000,1200000,1400000, 1600000,1800000,2000000,2200000`  I would like to be able to see `800K, 1M, 1.2M, 1.4M, 1.6M, 1.8M, 2M, 2.2M`.  Right now I have `800K, 1.M, 1.2M, 1.4M, 1.6M, 1.8M, 2.M, 2.2M`.  Your example would require me to define a range for every possible grouping of a million.

Comment: There are limits to the number of conditional statements you can put into a custom number format. use a *helper* column beside the actual numbers on the worksheet with ROUND and TEXT to generate the chart's axis labels.